# Animation effect on Star image to be displayed on Result activity of an android game

Tags: android, animation, android-xml

I am developing a game in android in which after completion of each level a Result activity gets displayed showing user's score and according to that score stars are given. Now on that Result activity there are **3 imageviews** of **grey colored stars** and on those I want to display with **animation golden stars**. But on playing animation the grey colored stars get hidden and only golden colored star seems moving and gets placed over the hidden grey star.
I want to know how can I make that **leftmost grey star remain visible** till a **golden star comes and sits on it**

Problem: The golden star comes and sits on the invisible grey star,but the grey star should have been visible till the golden star comes and settle down on it completely

[image]

Problem: The leftmost star gets invisible during the beginning of animation.

[image]

Java Code:

```
Myanim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.alpha_scale_left);
starIv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.starGrey1ImageView);

starIv1.clearAnimation();
starIv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
starIv1.startAnimation(Myanim1);
```

animation-xml

```
<translate
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromXDelta="-300%"
 android:toXDelta="0%"
 android:fromYDelta="-700%"
 android:toYDelta="0%"
 android:duration="1200"  
 android:zAdjustment="bottom"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
</translate>

<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1200"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"

    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    </rotate>
```

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can't, You have to add new ImageView on top of the current on and that animate it. You can keep 3 grey stars as one ImageView and add 3 ImageViews for Golden Stars which will be hidden and animate them.

If you want to avoid it, just make double animation. Like grey start disappear
and after gold appear

Something like this:
anim1 - grey go away
amim2 - golden enter

```
starIv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.starGrey1ImageView);

starIv1.clearAnimation();
anim1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            starIv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                            starIv1.startAnimation(anim2);
        }
    })
starIv1.startAnimation(anim1);
```